# i have to set 4 boxes in a 2x2 grid but when i try to organize them, only the 2 top ones are affected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[This is how i want my boxes to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu7uB.png), but when i try to organize them, only 2 of them work.
i tried putting background-color to see if the code is affecting the 4 boxes but only 2 light up. what am i doing wrong?

```css
#boxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: aqua;

  height: 200px;
  width: 35%;
  
}

.Art {
  display:block;
  font-size:larger;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  justify-content: center;

}
#cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="Art"><b>Artigo 1</b>
    <p id="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit. Sed urna arcu, iaculis in auctor at, scelerisque eget nunc.
      Praesent tincidunt purus nisi. Morbi cursus ex non facilisis elementum.
      Sed varius in nisi at fringilla. Morbi ullamcorper justo neque, nec ornare nisl pellentesque in.
      Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; </p></div>
      <div class="Art"><b>Artigo 3</b>
      <p id="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit. Sed urna arcu, iaculis in auctor at, scelerisque eget nunc.
        Praesent tincidunt purus nisi. Morbi cursus ex non facilisis elementum.
        Sed varius in nisi at fringilla. Morbi ullamcorper justo neque, nec ornare nisl pellentesque in.
        Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; </p></div>
      <div class="Art"><b>Artigo 2</b>
      <p id="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit. Sed urna arcu, iaculis in auctor at, scelerisque eget nunc.
        Praesent tincidunt purus nisi. Morbi cursus ex non facilisis elementum.
        Sed varius in nisi at fringilla. Morbi ullamcorper justo neque, nec ornare nisl pellentesque in.
        Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; </p></div>
      <div class="Art"><b>Artigo 4</b>
      <p id="cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit. Sed urna arcu, iaculis in auctor at, scelerisque eget nunc.
        Praesent tincidunt purus nisi. Morbi cursus ex non facilisis elementum.
        Sed varius in nisi at fringilla. Morbi ullamcorper justo neque, nec ornare nisl pellentesque in.
        Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; </p></div>
  </div>
```

i tried removing divs, adding new divs, expecting it to start affecting the 4 boxes but it kept affecting only the 2 top ones

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is very hard to understand in your question. Maybe a picture of your expected result? As of the background-color, it only applies to the div it is affected to: your container div. And that div is limited by height.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID. This is invalid HTML. IDs which aren't unique don't identify anything. They also don't behave as you'd expect with respect to CSS and JavaScript, which only selects the _first_ element with a particular ID. Use classes instead.